# Cannot create foreign key on 2 VARCHAR(45) columns in MySQL Workbench 6.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a foreign key. The columns in both tables are VARCHAR(45) and neither is a PK, however I keep getting this error message:

[image]

It is saying the PK of reference table is INT, which is true, but I am not referencing this column, I am referencing another column in this table that is VARCHAR(45).

I have already made to FK in this same table where both columns are VARCHAR(45), which is why I am wondering what I am doing wrong this time.

**UPDATE:**

Just figured it out.

The reference table column needed to be a Unique Index, then the foreign key worked.

Not a DB guy, but that sounds like a rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: can u share the schema or table structure or fields of table?

Comment: @user44730: Right, a FK should always reference either a PRIMARY or a UNIQUE key (i.e. a column or columns with a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint or a `UNIQUE` constraint).

Comment: Why don't you put the answer into an answer rather than an edit to the question? Answering your own questions *is* allowed, encouraged even.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, what i can deduce is that a foreign key is trying to reference a table with a primary key of int, while it also has a primary key of int set on it's table, a bit confusing.

But try removing the primary  key on the referencing table like table two below, it should work fine.
so you could do something like

`TABLE 1                   TABLE 2
Id(int)(pk)                   id(int)
name(varchar) ------ frontname(varchar)(fk)`

or

`TABLE 1                   TABLE 2
Id(int)(pk)                   id(int)(pk)
name(varchar)(pk2) ------ frontname(varchar)(pk2)(fk)`

Not sure of the second one though